# Track Maven command status in powershell

Tags: powershell, maven, maven-3

I have a powershell script where i am doing the below actions.

1 clone 4 Different GIT Repo
2 Build the same

Now the problem is i am having is the below piece of code of building

```
try
    {
        echo "Initiating mvn Install for msg-lib"
        mvn -f "***\pom.xml" clean install
        echo "mvn Install for * Completed"  
    }
catch
    {
        echo "We had failure in Building the Code for *, the pipeline will fail now"
        $returnStatus = 1   
    }
```

Like this i have four block each for 1 application , now i want that if there is any failure in building i.e. if the BUILD FAILS , then it should get tracked in the catch block and eventually exit the ps script with exit status as 1

But right now even if there is any build failure it moves to the next stage without failing.

Please help on how i would be able to track the build status from the clean install maven command ?

I tried using `Invoke-Expression` but it tracks the complete build log rather than the exact status

```
Invoke-Expression "mvn -f *\pom.xml' clean install") | Tee -variable result
```

Need a way to check the status of maven build , was it good or bad

Answer (score 0):

When you run a batch script or power shell script to execute maven command, it is similar to a script from outside and that script will run in its own way. It means your script is delegating a task to another script. There are two possibilities, the other may succeed or it may fail. You have track manually whether there is a failure. You have to in the following manner.

```
set mvnBuildError=0
if not errorlevel 0 set mvnBuildError=1
if %mvnBuildError%==1 (
    REM do other stuffs
)
```

Comment: Sambit, i did not understood the above block , can you please elaborate on that , also where  do i put my maven command in this ?

Comment: mvnBuildError is set to 0, it means there is no error, while running maven command, you may face problem, I mean build failure, in that mvnBuildError will be set to 1.